# Expiry date of source org?

Tags: date

I signed up for two developer editions about three months ago and today I received the notification that it is about to expire.

**Is there a process where I can see the actual date?**

[image: The Clock is Counting Down!]

Comment: That appears to be a trial org, not a Developer Edition Org.  Trials expire, Developer Edition doesn't.  https://developer.salesforce.com/signup

Answer (score 1):

Login into your any of your developer editions then navigate to :

> Setup > Company Profile > Company Information

OR
just search "Company Information" in the quick find box

On that page, you can scroll down and see as below :

[image]